# get all user informations in one select?

Tags: mysql

I have a website to buy and sell things.

In one page I need to get all the informations about an user... his sells, buys, his name, his picture...

What I do is it:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM users WHERE user=?
SELECT count(id) as num FROM sells WHERE user=?
SELECT count(id) as num FROM buy WHERE user=?
SELECT count(user) as num FROM questions WHERE user=?
SELECT img FROM picture WHERE user=?
```

Can I use just one select to get all this information? (can anyone give me an example) Would it be faster/better or should I keep doing one select per table?

Comment: Potentially - at least using subqueries, joined together on user. Whether it is faster or not there is only one way to find out - try it!

Comment: nice! yeah, I will try! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.name, 
       count(s.id) sells_count,
       count(b.id) buy_count,
       count(q.user) question_count,
       p.img
 FROM users u, sells s, buy b, questions q, picture p
 WHERE u.user=?
and s.user = u.user
and b.user = u.user
and q.user = u.user
and p.user = u.user
```